# How to connect to a selenium grid hub in order to open IE?

Tags: selenium

I am using Selenium Grid Concept for IE. I have written the node script. But for HUB am not sure of the script. When I executed it am getting an error as "**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"**.

Here is the Node and Hub Script:

NODE:

```
Path\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -role node -hub http://**ipaddress**:4444/grid/register  -browser browserName="internet explorer",version=8.0,platform=WINDOWS -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=PathofIEDriverServer\IEDriverServer\IEDriverServer.exe" -port 4444
```

HUB:

```
Path\Java\jre7\bin\java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar -Dwebdriver.internetexplorer.driver=PathofIEDriverServer\IEDriverServer\IEDriverServer.exe -role hub
```

and when executing:

```
{
            string strNode = "http://" + strNodeIP + ":4444/wd/hub";
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.HasNativeEvents, false);
            capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
            //capabilities.SetCapability("newCommandTimeout", "180");
            capabilities.IsJavaScriptEnabled = true;
            Uri IP = new Uri(strNode);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(IP, capabilities);
}
```

the line `WebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(IP, capabilities);` throws the error.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: No one is there to give a reply

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to establish a connection to the node. You should be establishing a connection to the *hub*. It is the hub that talks to the node.

Comment: Hi Bryan,Actually i made some changes and now i could establish the connection, since am launching my IE in Web Driver i cannot able to attach it to watin. Do Watin Support Selenium Web Driver Concept?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. Watin and Selenium are two different ways to automate a browser, so in that sense they support the same concept, but they are two completely different products.

Answer (score 0):

im also having same scenario,

Now the connection as established.

By using the WATIN, we can able to automate in standalone system with the below code.

IE ie;

ie=Browser.AttachTo((Find.ByUrl(u => u.Contains(strSiteUrl)));

This will work for standalone system IE Browser,

Now, my doubt is that.
How can i attach the IE Browser in selenium grid(HUB and NODE) Communication.